# Form Load error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that I want to open focusing to a cell and also full screen. I am using the following code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

   DoCmd.Maximize
   Me!Cell5.SetFocus
End Sub
```

It keeps giving me an error

> object doesn't support  this property or method

What am I doing wrong? Could you please help me to fix this code?

Comment: If you really want to *"Thank for help"*, as you write, then please could you give some feed-back on the answer given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the focus on an element of a form during the `Load` event. Instead you should do that in the `Open` or `Activate` event:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Open()
    Me!Cell5.SetFocus
End Sub
```

or:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Activate()
    Me!Cell5.SetFocus
End Sub
```

However, instead of setting the focus on a particular element in code, go to the properties of that `Cell5` and set the `TabIndex` property to `0`. This will ensure that this element gets focus whenever the form is loaded.

Comment: @Codingrookie, did you try this? Could you give some feed-back on whether you still have a problem with this?